# Height of a child div matched to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

so I've looked around the site and know there are questions like this, but so many of them are for fluid-width layouts and I cannot get the techniques to work with what I am doing.

I am just styling a form, and am having troubles with how the browser resizes. You can see the divs I am working with and my problem in the image below.

[image]

As you can see, below the `.col-1-3` div, as the browser resizes, there's a little space that shows up. I would like to match the height of the `.col-1-3` to that of it's parent, `.formInput`.

Does anyone know anyway to go about doing this? I don't care if it's a hack or some sort of Javascript/jQuery solution.

**EDIT**

I'm sure you guys want some code, who wouldn't?

Here's some HTML for the first field and label on the form:

```
<div class="formInput">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-1-3 left">
            <label>
                <p class="right">AsQ a question <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}rd/images/arrow_right_small.png" /></p>
            </label>
        </div><!-- .col-1-3 -->         

        <div class="col-2-3 right">
            {{ form.name }} **Django code**
        </div><!-- .col-2-3 -->
    </div><!-- .grid -->
```

Here's all of the necessary CSS for said field:

```
.right { float: right: }

.left { float: left; }

.formInput { 
    border: 6px solid #A5C3D2;
    display: block; 
    margin-bottom: 25px;    

    behavior: url('./scripts/border-radius.htc');
    border-radius: 18px;
    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
}

.formInput .col-1-3 { 
    background: #006180; 
    color: #FDBA63;
    text-align: right;

    behavior: url('./scripts/border-radius.htc');
    border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
    border-top-left-radius: 12px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
}

.formInput .col-1-3 label p { width: 220px; }

/* Grid */
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

/* Grid Gutters */
[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

[class*='col-']:last-of-type { padding-right: 0; }

.col-2-3 { width: 66.66%; }

.col-1-3 { width: 33.33%; }
```

If you guys want to see a working example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qMgwz/

Comment: Some code might help.

Comment: For sure, got that added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to the parent element of `.col-1-3`.

Then give `.col-1-3` a `position:absolute; height:100%;`

You'll want to make sure you apply a `margin-left` to the right half.

See this example (based on the code you provided): http://jsfiddle.net/ULM5s/1/

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the help. In fact, that did sort of work, but now the right column is sitting behind those labels that are on the form: http://i.imgur.com/70J5SxU.png

Comment: Edited the answer to include a `margin-left` to your right half, and forked your jsfiddle to show the new code. You don't need to add the `left` and `right` class anymore.

Comment: That's perfect man, thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.